# How can i identify image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, pixel

I have an object which does not have a geometrical shape to find length and  width easily, but i want to write code to measure average length and width by finding longest and smallest and the dividing by two. I have this code:

```
And it outputs this [image]
```

Comment: So, you have already solved the problem. `w,h` is the answer. Or do you want something else?

Comment: but they  gave me ractangle's size, and i wanted to find more accurate results by iteratting through pixels and finding end length. Or w h are most accurate i can get?

Comment: Maybe you could add a second, marked-up image showing exactly what you consider to be the length and width that you want to measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a two-step solution

---

- 1. Apply Canny
- 2. Find the length using `line-detector`

---

Applying [Canny](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) will give the result:

[image]

Now it is easier to find us to find the length:

[image]

Code:

---

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("JxHmm.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cny = cv2.Canny(gry, 50, 200)
lns = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector().detect(cny)
cpy = img.copy()

(h, w) = cpy.shape[:2]

min_x = w
min_y = h
max_x = 0
max_y = 0

for ln in lns:
    x1 = int(ln[0][0])
    y1 = int(ln[0][1])
    x2 = int(ln[0][2])
    y2 = int(ln[0][3])

    min_x = min(x1, x2, min_x)
    min_y = min(y1, y2, min_y)
    max_x = max(x1, x2, max_x)
    max_y = max(y1, y2, max_y)

    # print("Coords: ({}, {})->({}, {})".format(x1, y1, x2, y2))


cv2.line(cpy, pt1=(min_x, min_y), pt2=(max_x, min_y), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=10)
cv2.putText(cpy, '({}, {})'.format(min_x, min_y), (min_x - 10, (min_y - 30)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2,
            (0, 255, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.putText(cpy, '({}, {})'.format(max_x, min_y), (max_x - 340, (min_y - 30)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2,
            (0, 255, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.putText(cpy, '{} pixel'.format((max_x - min_x)), (int((max_x + min_x)/2), (min_y - 30)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            2, (0, 255, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.line(cpy, pt1=(min_x, min_y), pt2=(min_x, max_y), color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=10)
cv2.putText(cpy, '({}, {})'.format(min_x, min_y), (min_x - 10, (min_y + 50)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2,
            (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.putText(cpy, '({}, {})'.format(min_x, max_y), (min_x - 10, (max_y - 10)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2,
            (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.putText(cpy, '{} pixel'.format(max_y - min_y), (min_x - 150, int((max_y + min_y)/2) + 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2,
            (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow("cpy", cpy)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

an example like can access height, width and number of channels from img.shape: Height is at index 0, Width is at index 1; and number of channels at index 2.

```
import cv2
# read image
img = cv2.imread('/home/img/python.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
 
# get dimensions of image
dimensions = img.shape
 
# height, width, number of channels in image
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
channels = img.shape[2]
 
print('Image Dimension    : ',dimensions)
print('Image Height       : ',height)
print('Image Width        : ',width)
print('Number of Channels : ',channels)
```

Output :

```
Image Dimension    :  (149, 200, 4)
Image Height       :  149
Image Width        :  200
Number of Channels :  4
```

you can also find a more complete library at https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/

Comment: It is a properties of image, right? but  i need to work with an object

Answer (score 0):

In this page https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html they show how to calculate all the properties of a contour if you want to look, anyway with cv2.boundingRect(cnt) already calculated an approximate rectangle with the measures of width and height (w,h) I made a small program to draw this rectangle with its measures, the result is the following one:
[image]

Comment: If you want more accuracy I recommend that you find the extreme points as indicated on the page, and with that you calculate the respective measurements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1 - area inside contour:

```
area = cv.contourArea(cnt)
```

2 - Equivalent Diameter - the diameter of the circle whose area is same as the contour area

```
equi_diameter = np.sqrt(4*area/np.pi)
```

3 - Contour Perimeter - It is also called arc length.

```
perimeter = cv.arcLength(cnt,True)
```